# How to show that $\text{Man}(M,\mathbb{R}^n)\cong \mathbb{R}\text{-Alg}(C^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n),C^\infty(M))$?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, ct.category-theory, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds

I'm trying to show that manifolds are affine, i.e. $\text{Man}(M,N)\cong \mathbb{R}\text{-Alg}(C^\infty(N),C^\infty(M)) $. If I could show this for $N=\mathbb{R}^n$, then I know how to do the rest using the strong Whitney's embedding theorem. But it seems hard to show the surjectivity of $ \text{Man}(M,\mathbb{R}^n)\hookrightarrow \mathbb{R}\text{-Alg}(C^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n),C^\infty(M)):f\mapsto f^*$.

I found this post [Are all manifolds are affine?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/88986/are-all-manifolds-affine), but it didn't mention any explicit material about this, and I failed finding anything other than that post. I learned that $\text{Man}(M,\mathbb{R}^n)\cong C^\infty\text{-Ring}(C^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n),C^\infty(M))$ from *Models for Smooth Infinitesimal Analysis*, but I don't know how to show that $C^\infty\text{-Ring}(C^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n),C^\infty(M))\cong \mathbb{R}\text{-Alg}(C^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n),C^\infty(M))$.

Thanks in advance for any solution or material about this.

**EDIT:** I had a further investigation (but no success) and I'm putting it here with supplementary details of my question.

The images of the coordinates functions on $\mathbb{R}^n$ consist to give a map $ \mathbb{R}\text{-Alg}(C^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n),C^\infty(M))\to \text{Man}(M,\mathbb{R}^n)$, which tells the injectivity of $ \text{Man}(M,\mathbb{R}^n)\hookrightarrow \mathbb{R}\text{-Alg}(C^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n),C^\infty(M))$. To show the desired surjectivity, we still need to verify that the composition $$\mathbb{R}\text{-Alg}(C^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n),C^\infty(M))\to \text{Man}(M,\mathbb{R}^n)\hookrightarrow \mathbb{R}\text{-Alg}(C^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n),C^\infty(M))$$
is the identity.

I find that it suffices to show that, for any $\mathbb{R}$-algebra homomorphism $\varphi:C^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n)\to C^\infty(M)$, if $\rho\in C^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n)$ satisfies $\rho|_V=0$ for some open subset $V\subset\mathbb{R}^n$, then $\varphi(\rho)|_{f^{-1}(V)}=0$, where $f:M\to \mathbb{R}^n$ is given by the images of the coordinate functions on $\mathbb{R}^n$ under $\varphi$. If this is true, then we can define the restriction of $\varphi$ to any open subset $U\subset \mathbb{R}^n$,

$$ \varphi|_U :C^\infty(U)\to C^\infty(f^{-1}(U)),$$

by putting, for any $g\in C^\infty(U)$, $\varphi|_U(g)$ to be the unique smooth function such that

$$\varphi|_U(g)|_{f^{-1}(V)}=\varphi(G)|_{f^{-1}(V)} $$

for any open set $V\subset U$ and $G\in C^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n)$ such that $G|_V=g|_V$; to show that $\varphi(G)|_{f^{-1}(V)} $ does not depend on the choice of $G$ requires exactly the property I claimed above.

If the restrictions of $\varphi$ can be defined, then we obtain a sheaf morphism. Investigating the germs and we can find that $\varphi$ is indeed the pullback by $f$.

Comment: For an $\mathbb{R}$-algebra map, what are the images in $C^\infty(M)$ of the coordinate functions on $\mathbb{R}^n$?  When you put those coordinate functions together, does that give a manifold morphism to $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: @JasonStarr Surely it does. But to show that $\text{Man}(M,\mathbb{R}^n)\hookrightarrow \mathbb{R}\text{-Alg}(C^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n),C^\infty(M))$ is surjective, we need to verify that the image of this manifold morphism under $C^\infty$ is indeed the given $\mathbb{R}$-algebra map. This is exactly where I get stuck.

Comment: You might want to compare this paper by Mrčun, though his technique of proof goes in a rather different direction to yours: https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0309179

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The proof of this fact is available in modern textbooks.

For example, see Theorem 7.16 in Jet Nestruev's *Smooth Manifolds and Observables* (Second Edition, 2020).

In fact, the cited book contains a lot of material that explains how to pass between differential geometric objects and the corresponding algebraic objects, e.g., vector bundles and modules, differential forms and Kähler differentials, etc.

Comment: That's an amazing book! The key is in fact Theorem 7.2, which identifies a manifold with the dual of its algebra of smooth functions; under this identification, the composition $\mathbb{R}\text{-Alg}(C^\infty(N),C^\infty(M))\to \text{Man}(M,N)\hookrightarrow \mathbb{R}\text{-Alg}(C^\infty(N),C^\infty(M)) $ is exactly "taking twice duals", and Theorem 3.8 tells that it is indeed the identity. Thanks!

Comment: Would you mind giving me some materials about the fact that "supermanifolds are affine"? I once thought that I can prove that by using "manifolds are affine", but it turns out that the same gap in my question stops me from doing so.

Comment: @Shana: This follows from the affineness of ordinary manifolds combined with [Batchelor's theorem](https://doi.org/10.2307/1998201): every supermanifold is isomorphic to the supermanifold given by the sheaf of sections of the exterior algebra bundle of a finite-dimensional vector bundle.

Comment: I see! So the Batcherlor's theorem gives a projection from a supermanifold to its underlying ordinary manifold, and an argument using the trick of bump and the affineness of ordinary manifolds gives my desired local property. Thanks so much!